# Connect to ssas database with rest api?

Tags: api, ssas

H,
Is there a way to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) database with rest api?
I need to see the tables existsing in the ssas with rest api (via data factory web activity) but i cant find a way to do that.
I know i can connect to the server(to refresh and so on) but i cant find a way to connect to the database. i also know that there is an option for linked server and middle-tier application but i need it to be with rest api.
From a search on the net I saw that in 2001 there was no such option, maybe someone knows if something has changed?
Really appreciated any help.